# How to prove that log(1+x) and (1+x^2) do not intersect?

Tags: function, math, transcendental-equation

I tried converting to exponential,
e^(1+x^2) -x -1 = 0
Then finding a contradiction but didn't find one.
Then i differentiated to find a minima > 0.
2xe^(1+x^2) -1 = 0
but didn't find a solution as the term 2xe^(1+x^2) doesn't equal to 1 at any point x. Again even if there was any it still would have been a local minima.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question. It is a mathematics question.

Comment: i gave tag as math and transcendental equations?

Comment: This is a computer programming site. Perhaps you want https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AdityaJha Read the tag descriptions to see why math-only questions are off-topic on SO. Also, `log(1+x) <= x < 1 + x^2`.

Answer (score 1):

Let f(x) = 1 + x^2 - log(1 + x)

Conditional: x > -1

f'(x) = 2x -1/(1+x)

f'(x) = 0 => x = (sqrt(3) - 1) / 2

f"(x) = 2 + 1/(1+x)^2, always greater than 0

So f(sqrt(3) - 1) / 2) must be the minimum value of f

f(sqrt(3) - 1) / 2) is approximate 0.8

So f(x) always greater than 0.8

Therefore, f(x) = 0 has no solution.

Therefore log(1+x) and (1+x^2) do not intersect.